# Running Syntaxnet on Windows

Tags: windows, machine-learning, tensorflow, syntaxnet

Is there a way to get Syntaxnet running on Windows 8. I am new to Syntaxnet and Tensorflow ecosystem. Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running syntaxnet in a [docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) container using this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/Dockerfile) or a similar one.  See for example: https://github.com/brianlow/syntaxnet-docker.